# Put EditText like iPhone UITextField

Tags: android, android-edittext

In Android how can I make `EditText` look and work like iPhone `UITextField`? In `EditText` hint has a default font size how can I reduce it so it can look completely like the iPhone one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this in your layout file.

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/AccountNameText" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="14dip" 
    android:background="#00000000" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
    android:hint="@string/setaccountname" 
    android:textColorHint="#778BB0" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:textColor="#778BB0" 
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:textSize="13sp" />
```